# Does the current Windows Phone Toolkit contain all earlier releases?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

If I install the current release of the Silverligt Toolkit for Windows Phone (Nov 11), do I have to install the earlier releases as well in order to have everything or does the current release contain everything released before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no the current release of the Silverlight Toolkit contains everything

Comment: I will, but I have to wait a couple of minutes until it is even possible to validate ;-)

Comment: Note that some things from the earlier versions of the toolkit (such as GestureListeners) are now deprecated though.